# Bat file to recurse sub-directories and do Something

Tags: recursion, batch-file

I need to write a .bat file that will recurse through a directory structure and convert all epubs to mobis on the command line. I have Calibre installed, and the basic command-line for this is

```
ebook-convert MyFile.epub MyFile.mobi.
```

I'm sure this is a synch for someone out there, but I have been trying to do it half the morning without success.

Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

OK, eventually got it to work:

```
FOR /r "THE_FOLDER I AM RECURSING TO/" %%f IN (*.epub) do (
SET FILE= %%f
SET TITLE=!FILE:~1,-5!
ebook-convert %%f "!TITLE!.mobi"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for /r %I in (*.epub) do "ebook-convert.exe" "%I" "%~nI.mobi"
```

Good luck!

Comment: just to mention: for use in batchfiles, use `%%I` instead of `%I`