# recursive .bat file to apply jpegtran and pngout to all images in subfolders

Tags: batch-file, recursion

I have this script to optimize images inside a directory, I need to make this recursive in order to optimize all images in subdirectories, leaving filenames and folder structure unchanged.. Anyone can help to modify this code in order to modify images in subdirectories too?

```
@echo none
cd %1
md "%~1\OptimizedJPEGS"
for %%i in (*.jpg) do "C:\imageoptimization\jpegtran.exe" -optimize -progressive -copy none "%%i" "%~1\OptimizedJPEGS\%%i"
move /Y "%~1\OptimizedJPEGS\*.*" "%~1"
rd "%~1\OptimizedJPEGS"
for %%i in (*.png) do "C:\imageoptimization\pngout.exe" "%%i"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bat file to recurse sub-directories and do Something](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083971/bat-file-to-recurse-sub-directories-and-do-something)

Comment: not a duplicate, and the other thread is really lacking of information. Also, this thread can help many people since I could not find such a tutorial for jpegtran and pngout in google...

Comment: It doesn't matter what programs are being run. The question asks about recursively running a program in subdirectories, and the post I linked demonstrates exactly that (which is why it's a duplicate). :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work when launched in the main folder of the image tree.
Test it on some sample folders first.

```
@echo none
for /d /r %%a in (*) do (
   pushd "%%a"
     echo processing "%%a"
     md "OptimizedJPEGS" 
        for %%i in (*.jpg) do "C:\imageoptimization\jpegtran.exe" -optimize -progressive -copy none "%%i" "OptimizedJPEGS\%%i"
        move /Y "OptimizedJPEGS\*.*" .
     rd "OptimizedJPEGS"
        for %%i in (*.png) do "C:\imageoptimization\pngout.exe" "%%i" 
   popd
)
```